# styling in java script with specific condition

Tags: javascript

```
var res=document.getElementById("panel");
    var wid = window.innerWidth;
if(wid <= 900){
    res.setAttribute("id", "panel2");
}
```

I want to change some styling depends on the size of the browser ( to make it more responsive ) , but what I have tried did not worked :(

see more :https://ahmadahmadahmad.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Why not just use a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: because i ant to add a java script also

Comment: Depends on where and when you call that code. Please provide a [mcve] along with a properly detailed problem description and explanation of expected behavior. See [ask]

Comment: Also why change id , seems like an odd concept?

Comment: @charlietfl i want to add js code and change the layout ( to make an drop down menu for mobile view )

Comment: What does that have to do with changing an ID? And where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @charlietfl
https://ahmadahmadahmad.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @KaelWatts-Deuchar thanks that helped alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code only executes once when it is loaded.
To make the function being called when something happens, you need to attach it to an event listener.

In this case, you may want the panel changed when the screen is resized.
So, attached the function to `window.onresize` event listener.
The function will then be triggered when you resize the screen.

The code is as below. (I use `body` element as an example instead)

```
var res=document.querySelector("body");

window.onresize = function () {
  var wid = window.innerWidth;
  if(wid <= 900){
      res.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
  }
}
```

You can drag the screen size to see if the background color changed when width under 900px.
Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: var res=document.querySelector("body");
i want panel not body

Comment: this is only an example, you can use panel if you want, just modified to ‘document.querySelector(“.panel”)’

Comment: glad it helped！

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the resize event

```js
let res=document.getElementById("panel");
let wid = window.innerWidth;
if(wid <= 900){
    res.setAttribute("id", "panel2");
}


function Init(){
   wid = window.innerWidth;
if(wid <= 900){
    res.setAttribute("id", "panel2");
}else{res.setAttribute("id", "panel");}
}

setTimeout(function() {
  Init();
  addEventListener("resize", Init, false);
}, 15);
```

```css
[id^="panel"]{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:green;
}

#panel2{background:blue;}
```

```html
<div id="panel"></div>
```

Comment: sorry but still the same :(